# Bash - How to make a program continue on with an if statement rather than having to duplicate code?

Tags: bash, if-statement, arguments, continue

I swear I'm hear everyday, sorry if I am starting to become a nuisance, anyways here's some code example:

e.g. Program "Ask Name"

```
if [ $0 -eq 0 ] || [ $0 -eq $1 ]
then
      if [ $# -eq 0 ]
      then
           echo "Sir I insist, I must know your name"
           read $1
      fi   
      #[the long code for if the number of arguments =1 goes here!!]
      #the long code isn't important just imagine some fancy code here
      #fancy code
      #more fancy code
fi
```

Basically I just want it so that after the if statement the user can somehow amend the number of arguments and then continue on with the rest of the script.

At the moment the user just constantly has to input something and it never stops, most likely because the '$1' as a variable doesn't work.

Although the main reason I am asking this is to find out if there is a way to get away from the if statement and carry on with the program EVEN IF the argument entered meets specific criteria.

another example of what I mean if you don't understand me:

```
#takes name as argument
if [ $1 == "dave" ]
then
    echo "I don't like people called Dave, give me another name"
    [SOMETHING HERE THAT MAKES $1 THIS INPUT, NOT SURE ABOUT 'read $1']
else 
    echo "Your name is cool, come inside!"
fi
```

The example is a bit bad but I basically want it so that from the echo message the user will be able to continue with the code despite being called Dave.

As always, I appreciate any advice.

[IN THE TITLE I MENTION DUPLICATE]

I am basically referring to instead having to duplicate all of the other code and place it under the two different if statements. This is the only solution I can currently think of.

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094178/combine-two-bash-while-loop-statements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the `set` command:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Sir I insist, I must know your name"
    read name
    set -- "$name"
fi
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    # This is guaranteed to be true if $# was originally 0
    # It won't be true if the user original provided 2 or more arguments.
fi
```

---

```
if [ "$1" = "dave" ]
then
    echo "I don't like people called Dave, give me another name"
    read name
    shift  # discard the original first argument
    set -- "$name" "$@"
else 
    echo "Your name is cool, come inside!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, instead of IF statements it might be better to learn how to use **case**. An [example](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html) of case:

```
space=`df -h | awk '{print $5}' | grep % | grep -v Use | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -d "%" -f1 -`

case $space in
[1-6]*)
  Message="All is quiet."
  ;;
[7-8]*)
  Message="Start thinking about cleaning out some stuff.  There's a partition that is $space % full."
  ;;
9[1-8])
  Message="Better hurry with that new disk...  One partition is $space % full."
  ;;
99)
  Message="I'm drowning here!  There's a partition at $space %!"
  ;;
*)
  Message="I seem to be running with an nonexistent amount of disk space..."
  ;;
esac
```

And if we take your 2nd example to work:

```
case $1 in
dave)
  echo "I don't like people called Dave, give me another name"
  ;;
*)
  echo "Your name is cool, come inside!"
  ;;
esac
```